# load image using imagick in php

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick

I tried to apply a watermark onto an image using imagick but unable to load image using imagick

this is what i am trying

```
<?php
// Open the original image
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage("lion.jpg");
 
// Open the watermark
$watermark = new Imagick();
$watermark->readImage("1.png");
 
// Overlay the watermark on the original image
$image->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
 
// send the result to the browser
header("Content-Type: image/" . $image->getImageFormat());
echo $image;

?>
```

when ever I run this code I got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `lion.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2617' in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagick.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\imagick.php(4): Imagick->readimage('lion.jpg') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagick.php on line 4
```

both the code and the images are in the same directory.

and I am using ImageMagick 6.7.7-4 2012-05-29 Q16 on Windows

Comment: Have you made sure the permissions for the file make it so php can read that file?

Comment: yes i use this image using gd several time through php

Comment: Have you checked if your path to the files are right? test file_exists("lion.jpg") and se what you get. or is_readable()

Comment: file_exists("lion.jpg"); and is_readable() both return 1

Comment: What happens if you pass the absolute path?
$image->readImage(realpath("lion.jpg"));

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 

<?php
// Open the original image
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage("C:/xampp/htdocs/projectname/lion.jpg");

// Open the watermark
$watermark = new Imagick();
$watermark->readImage("C:/xampp/htdocs/projectname/1.png");

// Overlay the watermark on the original image
$image->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

// send the result to the browser
header("Content-Type: image/" . $image->getImageFormat());
echo $image;

?>
```

Comment: yes this work thanks but i think this is not the right way to do

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Imagick::mergeImageLayers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.mergeimagelayers.php) like this:

```
$img1 = new Imagick(realpath('lion.jpg'));
$img2 = new Imagick(realpath('1.png'));

// in case you need to add opacity...
$img2->setImageOpacity(.5);// between 0.0 and 1.0

$img2->setImagePage($img2->getImageWidth(), $img2->getImageHeight(), 0, 0);
$img1->addImage($img2);

$result = $img1->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_COMPOSITE);
$format = 'jpg';
$result->setImageFormat($format);

header('Content-Type: image/'.$format);
echo $result->getImageBlob();
```

> This assumes the images are the same width for simplification

Answer (score 0):

You may get this type of error on trying to open the SVG image also. To open a SVG image install following package.

```
sudo apt-get install librsvg2-bin
```

Refer: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576627